# How to control Video in iframe on IPAD safari browser using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ipad, iframe

I am using the following code to run video in an `iframe`:

```
<iframe
    id="videoFrame"
    autoplay
    seamless
    width="100%"
    height="90%"
    src="video/abc.MP4">
<p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>  
</iframe>
```

Using the above code, video runs fine in all browsers and on iPad.  For controlling the video I am using the following code:

```
document.getElementById(
    "videoFrame"
).contentDocument.getElementsByTagName("video")[0].pause();
```

It works fine on all the desktop browsers.  The video is paused on click events.

But on iPad it returns `undefined`.

So please can anyone tell me how to control video in iframe on iPad safari browser...

Comment: Note that `autoplay` is for the `<video>` tag, not iframe...so this is not valid html5.  Something you can more likely ignore is that [html5 does not support percentages in the width and height fields](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-validator/2011Feb/0004.html), but the best thing to do is probably to do that with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Use `touchstart` , `touchmove` events for iPad.

Refer [this link](http://gregmurray.org/ipad/touch-events.html)

Comment: hi friend i dont want touch event or drag and drop i want to control video inside iframe and i want to control it on ipad safari on rest desktop browser i am able to control